# Is a butterfly network on 8-inputs planar?

Tags: graph-theory, self-learning, planar-graphs

I could prove that a four input butterfly network is planar. For that I simply drew it such that no two edges intersect. But I could not use the same approach for the 8-input butterfly network. So I tried doing the opposite by finding a subgraph of it which is a subdivision of either $K_{3,3}$ or $K_5$. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Can you please post a diagram of a butterfly network? I am not familiar with this particular diagram, but may be able to help. I found this diagram, but would like confirmation to make sure I'm on the same page: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:DIT-FFT-butterfly.png

Comment: This is a butterfly network with 8-inputs.http://www.doc.ic.ac.uk/~nd/surprise_95/journal/vol4/fcw/reportbtfly.gif

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is, in fact, not planar. Here is a subgraph that is a subdivision of $K_{3,3}$. I colored the degree 3 vertices red to (hopefully) make it easier to see.

[image]